# Mapping a Plant with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

There is a dataset of a plant that makes certain numeric outputs based on numeric inputs. The dataset contains the input values and output value for several years every 15 minutes.

Since it would be too expensive to model the physical properties of the system in software, I would like to create a model with Machine learning, which behaves as the system. When entering inputs, the model should provide output.

For the solution I have tested Feedforward neural network. The results are ok, but in some cases too inaccurate.

What other methods would be available for this problem?

Comment: Could you please supply some more information about the in- and outputs? Is it a classifier you're looking for a regression model?

Comment: @BastianSchoettle  
My dataset consists of 365 patterns (everyday of a year). One pattern consists of 96 floats (every 15 minutes). Same with the outputs. I am looking for a regression model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a time series task you could use the NARX architecture of a neural network or an LSTM network. Later is like the NARX a recurrent neural network. Matlab offers an implementation of the first one.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory

If you "simply" want to fit a polynomial to your data you could use basic linear regression with polynomials of different degree to see which one works best.
**Note:** It's not called linear because it's only able to fit linear models.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Some other possibilities are kernel methods such as kernel ridge regression or SVR. Later one is based on support vector machines which usually perform quite well (at least for classification from my personal experience). 
If you want to try SVR you can use a small but great lib called libSVM. Matlab also offers this.

The following link shows a comparison of this algorithms:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_kernel_ridge_regression.html

**Edit:** If i understand this correctly, it's a time series task if you want to predict the outputs of a future time `t+1` from a given time `t`. Try the NARX model or the LSTM net.